# CSS "display:flex" adds some unwanted space

Tags: css, flexbox

Is the picture below, we have a div container containing 5 items (icon + text). I would like to display those 5 items with always 3 items per column using flexbox. To do so, we can add flex-direction:column, flex-wrap:wrap and specify a height.

But, I would like the div container to adapt his height automatically to the height of the 3 items. So, for example, item height is 10px. Then, div container should automatically have a height of 30px.

I would like a response with flexbox in priority (in order to have a better understanding of them) but I'm open to other methods.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Likely what is happening is .sidebarNavigation is set to fill it's container's height - or the container is set to force it's children to do that.  Hard to see exactly what's going on with a screenshot though - replicate it in CodePen so we can see the source code (and quite possibly, the act of creating a reduced test case will make you see what the problem is yourself)

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention it. I added a note on the post.

Comment: Still, a reduced test case is needed.  Maybe some CSS master knows what the problem is, but generally we need to see actual code to be able to help.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: A changed the whole approch of the problem. Is it more understandable ?

Comment: No.  Add code.  It doesn't have to be production code - but a minimum reproducible example like is described in the link I posted before.  A question without code is almost certainly not going to get you any useful answers.

Comment: Please provide **your** code, preferably as a [MCVE], so we can address the issues with it. Don't just provide a specification and expect code as a result, Stack OVerflow is **not** a free code writing service.

Comment: Give a minimal reproducible example is possible when you have a behavior you don't understand in your code. Here, I don't had any code, I had only an angle of approch which was may be wrong. And, it was wrong, see accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox works the other way around, it reacts to its parent size.
I would suggest to use grid here:

```css
div {
 background: purple;
}

ul {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
 grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. "Flexbox works the other way around, it reacts to its parent size" was the best sentence you could give to explain how I was wrong. Answer accepted !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this on your main css

```
    *,*::before,*::after{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing:border-box}
```

If you didnt add this piece of code, that may be the reason. Because for default, css items have extra paddings and margins that we cannot observe easily.

Edit: Did you try my solution? It would be nice to let me know if you tried and it didnt work.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the whole approch of the question. First one was not well explained. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that your parent container doesn't have a `display:inline-block`